# How can I generate and display a grid of images in PyTorch with plt.imshow and torchvision.utils.make_grid?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, imshow, torchvision

I am trying to understand how torchvision interacts with mathplotlib to produce a grid of images. It's easy to generate images and display them iteratively:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w = torch.randn(10,3,640,640)
for i in range (0,10):
    z = w[i]
    plt.imshow(z.permute(1,2,0))
    plt.show()
```

However, displaying these images in a grid does not seem to be as straightforward.

```
w = torch.randn(10,3,640,640)
grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(w, nrow=5)
plt.imshow(grid)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-1601915e10f3> in <module>()
      1 w = torch.randn(10,3,640,640)
      2 grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(w, nrow=5)
----> 3 plt.imshow(grid)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3203                         filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad,
   3204                         imlim=imlim, resample=resample, url=url, data=data,
-> 3205                         **kwargs)
   3206     finally:
   3207         ax._hold = washold

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1853                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1854                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1855             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1856 
   1857         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5485                               resample=resample, **kwargs)
   5486 
-> 5487         im.set_data(X)
   5488         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5489         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
    651         if not (self._A.ndim == 2
    652                 or self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):
--> 653             raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
    654 
    655         if self._A.ndim == 3:

TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

Even though PyTorch's documentation indicates that w is the correct shape, Python says that it isn't. So I tried to permute the indices of my tensor:

```
    w = torch.randn(10,3,640,640)
    grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(w.permute(0,2,3,1), nrow=5)
    plt.imshow(grid)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-62-6f2dc6313e29> in <module>()
          1 w = torch.randn(10,3,640,640)
    ----> 2 grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(w.permute(0,2,3,1), nrow=5)
          3 plt.imshow(grid)

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision-0.2.1-py3.6.egg/torchvision/utils.py in make_grid(tensor, nrow, padding, normalize, range, scale_each, pad_value)
         83             grid.narrow(1, y * height + padding, height - padding)\
         84                 .narrow(2, x * width + padding, width - padding)\
    ---> 85                 .copy_(tensor[k])
         86             k = k + 1
         87     return grid

    RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (3) must match the existing size (640) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

What's happening here? How can I place a bunch of randomly generated images into a grid and display them?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There's a small mistake in your code. [`torchvision.utils.make_grid()`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.utils.make_grid.html#torchvision.utils.make_grid) returns a tensor which contains the grid of images. But the channel dimension has to be moved to the end since that's what matplotlib recognizes. Below is the code that works fine:

```
In [107]: import torchvision

# sample input (10 RGB images containing just Gaussian Noise)
In [108]: batch_tensor = torch.randn(*(10, 3, 256, 256))   # (N, C, H, W)

# make grid (2 rows and 5 columns) to display our 10 images
In [109]: grid_img = torchvision.utils.make_grid(batch_tensor, nrow=5)

# check shape
In [110]: grid_img.shape
Out[110]: torch.Size([3, 518, 1292])

# reshape and plot (because matplotlib needs channel as the last dimension)
In [111]: plt.imshow(grid_img.permute(1, 2, 0))
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).
Out[111]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7f62081ef080>
```

which shows the output as:

[image: torchvision_make_grid]

Comment: Thank you, kmario23. My mistake was failing to think of the grid as an image to be displayed, meaning that the grid would have to be reshaped :-)

Comment: Hi @kmario23, what is `grid_img.permute(1, 2, 0)` doing here? What is 1, 2, 0 here? Can you explain, please?

Comment: @Md.MusfiqurRahaman, As shown in `in [110] grid_img.shape`, the dimensions of grid_img are [# color channels x image height x image width]. Conversely, the input to matplotlib.pyplot.imshow() *needs to be* [image heigth x image width x # color channels] (i.e., the shape needs to be `[518, 1292, 3]`). The `.permute(1, 2, 0)` action is a Torch-specific function that permutes the axes of the original in exactly that order: [axis 1 x axis 2 x axis 0] = [image heigth x image width x # color channels].

Comment: There is also `torchvision.utils.save_image` which can avoid the need to permute and install matplotlib. `torchvision.utils.save_image(grid_img, 'filename.png')`

Answer (score 4):

You have to convert to numpy first

```
import numpy as np

def show(img):
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1,2,0)), interpolation='nearest')

w = torch.randn(10,3,640,640)
grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(w, nrow=10, padding=100)
show(grid)
```

Comment: Hi @iacolippo, (1, 2, 0) doing here? What is 1, 2, 0 here? Can you explain, please?

Comment: It's just transposing the image dimensions to put the color channel as last - i.e. going from `(color, width, height)` to `(width, height, color)`