# How does the shape of a tensor change after make_grid?

Tags: python, tensor

The question is with reference to
[How can I generate and display a grid of images in PyTorch with plt.imshow and torchvision.utils.make_grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329159/how-can-i-generate-and-display-a-grid-of-images-in-pytorch-with-plt-imshow-and-t/65865831?noredirect=1#comment116454849_65865831)

0

When you say that the shape of the tensor after make_grid is torch.Size([3, 518, 1292]). What does it mean? Do all the images combine to make a tensor of size? I thought the make_grid tensor would be of shape

2562 by 2565 i.e. 3, 512, 1280

Also, why do we need to convert a tensor to numpy before plotting it? Thanks